# Not able to generate Angular app based on running business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

When trying to follow the instructions (https://fabric-composer.github.io/tasks/genapp.html) to generate an Angular app based on a running business network I'm getting a No bower.json present error, using the defaultProfile.  It seems to generate a node_modules directory but it's empty, however no angular-app directory is created.  I was able to get the app generated by pointing at an existing BNA file as outlined in step 2 of the document but wasn't ideal.  Any idea of what mind be going on?

```
jdockter@ubuntu:~$ yo fabric-composer:angular
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/home/jdockter/config
WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
Welcome to the Angular2 skeleton app generator
? Do you want to connect to a running Business Network? Yes
? What is the name of the application you wish to generate?: angular-app
? Description of the application: Skeleton Fabric Composer Angular2 project
? Author name: Jon Dockter
? Author email: jdockter@us.ibm.com
? What is the Business Network Identifier?: labor-network-model
? What is the Connection Profile to use? defaultProfile
? Enrollment id: WebAppAdmin
? Enrollment Secret: DJY27pEnl16d
Configuring: angular-app
About to connect to a running business network


I'm all done. Running npm install && bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/jdockter/package.json'
npm WARN jdockter No description
npm WARN jdockter No repository field.
npm WARN jdockter No README data
npm WARN jdockter No license field.
bower                           ENOENT No bower.json present
Complete
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this defect to track this:
https://github.com/fabric-composer/fabric-composer/issues/206

Will update here as soon as we know more.

Thanks for the report.